# move from one page to another page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jquery-mobile

I am creating a mobile app using angular js and jquery mobile. The last page has a result table and there is a button for practise again.When I click that button the page is redirecting to another page but suddenly it is coming back to the last page which has the result.

html:

```
<p align="center"><a href="#pageone" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline" ng-click="redirect(sid);history.go(0)">Practise Again</a></p>
```

angular js:

```
$scope.redirect = function(stdid){
    $http.get('php/practiseagain.php?stud_id='+stdid).success(function(response) {
    document.getElementById('tab_display').innerHTML = " ";
    window.location = "#pageone";
});

    //document.location.reload(true);

}
```

It is redirectng to page one but in that fraction of second it is coming back to the result page. Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: could you make the JSFiddle for better understanding?

Comment: sorry Amol this cant be done in JSFiddle because I will have to put my whole app because the redirection problem comes after the first round of test there will be a button in the last page for practising again.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with what you are trying to do, starting from combination of jQuery and Angular. It's like asking how much salt to add to a soup when your other ingredients include machine oil. I'm honestly surprised that this is the only problem you are facing. To end on a constructive note, I suggest you either adopt Angular and read about how things are there, or stay with jQuery - don't mix.

Comment: ok can you put a demo New Dev

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **$routeProvider** for routing in your application you can use the **$location** service that Angular itself provides to redirect to a specific view:

```
$location.path('/pageone');
```

For scrolling to a specific part or element you can use $anchorScroll:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll